# Couchbase index creation for multiple filter criteria combinations in N1QL query

Tags: indexing, couchbase, sql++

We have two types of documents, **CS** and // when all optional filters are present  in same bucket, and we are joining the two using **latestCommandStatusId** field of **PCI** which is **id** of **CS** document and multiple optional and some mandatory fields in N1QL. The response time on the production server is taking too long, more than 5-6 seconds, we need to reduce it to sub 300 milliseconds.

We have two types of documents, CS and PCI in same bucket, and we are joining the two using latestCommandStatusId field of PCI which is id of CS document and multiple optional and some mandatory fields in N1QL.

```
CS(id = request10)
{
  "id": "request10",
  "_class": "CS",
  "status": "FAILED"
}


PCI(id = pci1)
{
  "id": "pci1",
  "latestCommandStatusId": "request10",  // equal to some CS doc id
  "_class": "PCI",
  "createdDateTime": 1672531200000,
  "effectiveDateTime": 1688083200000,
  "locationDSL": {
    "parameters": {
      "locationClusterId": ["L3", "L1","L2"]
    }
  },
  "productDSL": {
    "parameters": {
      "tpnb": ["02","04"]
    }
  }
}
```

Now  to join the these documents we have following query which is working fine but taking too long in the production server with huge dataset. My question what indexes we need to create to fasten the response time for the below filters combination

```
SELECT  META(pci).id AS _ID,META(pci).cas AS _CAS, pci,cs
FROM prices pci JOIN prices cs ON KEYS pci.latestCommandStatusId   // join CS and PCI on pci.latestCommandStatusId which is id of CS doc
WHERE pci.effectiveDateTime BETWEEN "some_from_time" AND "some_to_time"   // compulsory filter 
AND 'some_tpnb' IN pci.productDSL.parameters.tpnb   // optional filter if some_tpnb is null in request param
AND 'some_locationClusterId' IN pci.locationDSL.parameters.locationClusterId   // optional filter if some_locationClusterId is null in request param
AND  pci.state = "some_pci_state"  // optional filter if some_pci_state is null in request param
AND cs.status = "some_cs_status"   // optional filter if some_cs_status is null in request param
ORDER BY pci.effectiveDateTime DESC  //mandatory ordering by pci.effectiveDateTime DESCending order
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 15   // mandatory pagination
```

so we have some mandatory filters and some optional filters depending on the input

e.g if all  optional filters are null

```
WHERE pci.effectiveDateTime BETWEEN "some_from_time" AND "some_to_time"   // compulsory filter 
ORDER BY pci.effectiveDateTime DESC  //mandatory ordering by pci.effectiveDateTime 
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 15   // mandatory pagination
```

e.g  if some_tpnb is not null in request param and other optional filters are null

```
WHERE pci.effectiveDateTime BETWEEN "some_from_time" AND "some_to_time"   // compulsory filter 
AND 'some_tpnb' IN pci.productDSL.parameters.tpnb   // if some_tpnb is not null in request param and other optional filters are null
ORDER BY pci.effectiveDateTime DESC  //mandatory ordering by pci.effectiveDateTime 
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 15   // mandatory pagination
```

e.g: if some_locationClusterId is not  null & other optional filters are null

```
WHERE pci.effectiveDateTime BETWEEN "some_from_time" AND "some_to_time"   // compulsory filter 
AND 'some_locationClusterId' IN pci.locationDSL.parameters.locationClusterId   
ORDER BY pci.effectiveDateTime DESC  //mandatory ordering by pci.effectiveDateTime 
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 15   // mandatory pagination
```

e.g: if some_pci_state & some_cs_status is not  null & other optional filters are null

```
WHERE pci.effectiveDateTime BETWEEN "some_from_time" AND "some_to_time"   // compulsory filter 
AND  pci.state = "some_pci_state"   
AND cs.status = "some_cs_status"   
ORDER BY pci.effectiveDateTime DESC  //mandatory ordering by pci.effectiveDateTime DESCending order
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 15   // mandatory pagination
```

e.g: when all optional filters are present

```
WHERE pci.effectiveDateTime BETWEEN "some_from_time" AND "some_to_time"   
AND 'some_tpnb' IN pci.productDSL.parameters.tpnb   
AND 'some_locationClusterId' IN pci.locationDSL.parameters.locationClusterId   
AND  pci.state = "some_pci_state"  
AND cs.status = "some_cs_status"   
ORDER BY pci.effectiveDateTime DESC  //mandatory ordering by pci.effectiveDateTime  
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 15   // mandatory pagination
```

Answer (score 1):

try this and see if it helps

```
SELECT  META(pci).id AS _ID,META(pci).cas AS _CAS, pci,cs
FROM prices pci
JOIN prices cs ON KEYS pci.latestCommandStatusId
WHERE pci._class = "PCI"
      AND cs._class = "CS"
      AND pci.effectiveDateTime BETWEEN "some_from_time" AND "some_to_time"
      AND 'some_tpnb' IN pci.productDSL.parameters.tpnb
      AND 'some_locationClusterId' IN pci.locationDSL.parameters.locationClusterId
      AND  pci.state = "some_pci_state"
      AND  cs.status = "some_cs_status"
ORDER BY pci.effectiveDateTime DESC
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 15

CREATE INDEX ix1 ON prices(effectiveDateTime DESC,state) WHERE _class = "PCI";
```

Comment: will test it and let u know...but wouldn't we need multiple indexes depending on whether we have optional filters in the query?...can we have all query covered with  with just one covering index?